# Typesetting a figure over multiple pages

Tags: floats, subfloats

In my document, I have several images that would usually be combined as subfigures of one figure with a general caption.
Unfortunately, these images are so big that they will use up three pages in total. What would be the best way to typeset these, regarding captions and numberings? Should I keep them as subfigures and only have the caption after the last image? Or should I split them into separate figures, and maybe copy the caption to all of them?
Both ways do not seem right. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: That's a matter of personal opinion. I would split them into separate images, with caption on each one. Also indicate (in the captions) that each image is a sub-part of a larger, total image.

Comment: Matter of opinion. My decision would depend on the content, context etc. I'd caption them all regardless, though i.e. no matter which decision I made. But you need to be careful to refer to only the sub-figures if you do it that way, whether you caption them all or not.

Comment: What does this have to do with grid typesetting? Please don't add irrelevant tags willy-nilly.

Comment: @cfr My bad, I thought it applied here. Thanks for removing it.

Comment: Okay, than I will probably go with captioning them all. Still feels redundant to have the exact same caption three times, though...

Comment: It needs a better tag wiki, in that case ;). Grid typesetting is something LaTeX is essentially incapable of doing. Fortunately, you aren't trying to do that, so LaTeX's incapacity shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Not the exact same caption. Something like "Figure 4, part 1," and so forth.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the related issue is a matter of personal choice and not related to any  unresolved technical problem.

Comment: It is a subjective question, but to me it seemed okay to post it here, according to the guidelines about which subjective questions are allowed. Sorry if I was wrong.